# Forked process writing to closed file descriptor stderr

Tags: sockets, unix, exec, fork, file-descriptor

I've come across a scenario I'd like help understanding. Example code is below.

```
fclose(stdin);
fclose(stdout);
fclose(stderr);
int sockets[2];
assert(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) == 0);
int socketA = sockets[0];
int socketB = sockets[1];
assert(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) == 0);
int socketC = sockets[0];
int socketD = sockets[1];
assert(socketA == 0);
assert(socketB == 1);
assert(socketC == 2);
assert(socketD == 3);
unblock_socket(socketA);
unblock_socket(socketB);
unblock_socket(socketC);
unblock_socket(socketD);
unsigned char buffer = 0;
assert(::recv(socketA, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketC, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketB, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketD, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1)
    assertfalse;
else if (pid > 0)
{
    int status = 0;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else
{
    assert(execv("/usr/sbin/chown", nullptr) == 0) // Prints "usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]]..." to stderr
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
assert(::recv(socketA, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketC, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketB, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1);
assert(::recv(socketD, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1); // Assertion failed!. Reading from socket D we see "usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]]..."
```

I have closed stderr (file descriptor 2) and subsequently opened socket C which takes the now available file descriptor 2. However chown still seemingly manages to write its error output to file descriptor 2. Should chown not realise stderr was closed and file descriptor 2 re-assigned and therefore not write to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is performing exactly as it should.

You close stderr, then call socketpair(). SocketC == 2 (i.e. now stderr).

chown() inherits these file descriptors, so when it writes to stderr it's really writing to SocketC which the parent reads from SocketD.

Comment: So is it bad practice to close stderr? Because if I close stderr and then its file descriptor gets reused (e.g. for a socket, as in this case) then third party code could write to that socket at any point? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I should have been redirecting stdin/stdout/stderr to /dev/null so the file descriptors 0-2 are not reassigned. This is a daemon application.

However I still find it odd chown is printing to file descriptor 2. It seems to me chown prints using

```
dprintf(STDOUT_FILEERR, "usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]]...");
```

or perhaps

```
const char error[] = "usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]]...";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, error, sizeof(error) - 1);
```

instead of

```
fprintf(stderr, "usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]]...");
```

or something similar... as in the first example dprintf writes to socketC (file descriptor 2) which causes problems but in the second example fprintf realises the stderr FILE* object is closed and does not do the write.

Any further insight would be much appreciated.